# Adding multiple pages to a scrollview with interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have been combing the web on how to add custom views to a UIScrollView with interface builder but have not found a single clear example on how its done. What I want to do is create views using interface builder and display each of the views within the scroll view as pages. Most of the examples work with images, increments, and programmatically creating colored views  for the pages in the scrollview. Does anyone know how to create pages for their scrollview using interface builder? If so, would anyone be willing to share an example on how to do this?

Comment: I think the closest you will get is [page control](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `uipageviewcontroller` for this project. It creates exactly what you want. Here is a clear example in a form of tutorial as you requested which you may like to look at:

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

And here is the link to the doc's from apple

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html